# Картинки в ответах

Tags: обсуждение, answers

Предлагаю дополнить пункт справки, посвящённый ответам. Сами знаете почему - это очень, очень неудобно.

"Публикуйте ответ в виде изображения только в том случае, если по другому ответить не получается (ответ содержит принципиально важную диаграмму, схему, рукописный текст или иной рисунок) Допускается изображение печатного текста, если это редкое издание, которое нельзя найти в электронном виде или долго набирать)."